# Checkmarx Client DOM XSS Violation in ReachJS

Tags: javascript, security, next.js, xss, checkmarx

I have this message from Checkmarx:

> The application's = embeds untrusted data in the generated output with location, at line 19 of `****.js`. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

It is shown below code:

```
    const url = (window.location.href || '');
    const newHref = url.replace('parameter=12', '');
    if (newHref !== url) {
      window.location.href = newHref;
    } else {
      window.location.reload();
    }
```

I used `sanitizeHtml` and `JSON.stringify` `const url = window.location.href || ''`, but neither helped correct the problem. How is it possible to correct this type of error?

Comment: Hi, try to read your question as you don't know the case. I'm confused. The quotes from Checkmarx mentioned **line 19**, but you gave us **line 22/25**. Also, we can't understand your code, what the relation between the lines and what is `newHref` is?

Comment: See what a good question looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129064/how-to-avoid-path-traversal-issue-in-python-3-6. Quate the full Checkmarx message, and share all the relevant code.

Comment: In the report itself it says 19 but showing code snippet of 22 and 25. I updated the snippet to give more meaning.

Comment: Have you tried using `const url = new URL(window.location.href);`? Then use that to manipulate the URL.